# Why does my Image wrap on full width screen using IE 11?

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, flexbox

I'm having a problem with this code on IE 11 and edge, the 3rd image on the right wrap in to a second row while the window still at full width! but it shouldn't do that check code below.

The image or the `__article` div is it being responsive when I scale down the screen but it seems to work after 600 pixels. I did a lot of research about this but couldn't find any lead.

can anyone please help.

If you want to test the code you can use [**cross browser testing**](http://www.crossbrowsertesting.com) create free account and use live testing.

```css
*,
*:after,
*:before {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  outline: none;
}

.__main {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap; 
}

.__article {
  padding:5px;
  flex-basis: 33.33%;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
 .__article {
  padding:5px;
  flex-basis: 70%;
 margin: 0 auto;
}
}
```

```html
<div class="__main">
<div class="__article">
 <div class="div__img">
  <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/300x400" width="100%" />
 </div>
 <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.</p>
</div>
<div class="__article">
 <div class="div__img">
  <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/300x400" width="100%" />
 </div>
 <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.</p>
</div>
 <div class="__article">
 <div class="div__img">
  <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/300x400" width="100%" />
 </div>
 <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.</p>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please post your code in the question itself. http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: @Michael_B is that what you mean ?

Comment: @codechick external links are discouraged because they can be deleted at any time, which would cause future users looking for the same question to be totally lost. So it's better to include the code in the question itself, specially in the form of a Stack Overflow snippet.

Comment: @Michael_B Oh that make sense! I thought to add external link since its kinda long a bit I thought to make my post shorter. Thanks for the advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off, get rid of all those prefixes, they are certainly not needed, specially the webkit ones. MS prefixes might be needed if you're trying to support IE10, but not for IE11.

The element is wrapping because of the added padding. It seems **`box-sizing:border-box` and `display:flex` don't get along on IE 11**. 
So use flex-basis: `calc(33.33% - 10px);` to compensate for the two 5px paddings, and delete the `box-sizing:border-box` so other browsers don't get narrower widths, and it should work OK

```css
*,
*:after,
*:before {
  /*box-sizing: border-box;*/
  margin: 0;
  outline: none;
}

.__main {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap; 
}

.__article {
  padding:5px;
  flex-basis: calc(33.33% - 10px);
}
```

```html
<div class="__main">
<div class="__article">
 <div class="div__img">
  <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/300x400" width="100%" />
 </div>
 <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.</p>
</div>
<div class="__article">
 <div class="div__img">
  <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/300x400" width="100%" />
 </div>
 <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.</p>
</div>
 <div class="__article">
 <div class="div__img">
  <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/300x400" width="100%" />
 </div>
 <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.</p>
</div>
</div>
```

(I've deleted the media query for demonstration purposes on that SO snippet only)

Comment: That worked very well thanks! just one thing, why should I remove the prefixes? or you mean here in this case only?

Comment: @codechick WebKit prefixes are simply not needed for flexbox, all WebKit browsers support the unprefixed syntax. Code repetition should be avoided whenever possible, to save bandwidth, ease maintenance, and prevent issues. You might want to keep the ms prefixes if you want to support IE10, but if only aiming for I.E.11, they are also redundant https://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox